# Displaying data in different format in datalist

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, datalist

If I want to have several custom format of displaying data in for example asp.net DataList, what is the common way to to it.

Should I have more then one control so one control could display data in simple row format, other with different repeat direction or different number of columns, or is there a way to set it by playing with itemtemplate?

Comment: What do you mean by format? is it the styling of the generated HTML? or is it the structure of it?

Comment: it is not so clear what exactly you are trying to achieve without providing example code. Depending on your situation, you can also set related properties of a DataList from codebehind. So if your logic is on server side, you can set for example,         myDataList.RepeatLayout = RepeatLayout.Table
        myDataList.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal
        myDataList.RepeatColumns = 2